# How to change configuration of web apps

Tags: web-applications, configuration, gruntjs, gulp

My web app depends on some external services and has API access key values hardcoded in the source code.

Now I want to support multiple environments, like development and production. For each environment I want to use different set of services with different keys.

The question is how to change the keys in the source code when switching the environments?

As an obvious solution I can think of a script that patches the files using the environment variables. But with modern tools and technologies around web development I think there must be more elegant solution. I heard about `grunt`, but didn't find an appropriate plugin.

Comment: Are those hardcoded keys on the server side or on the client side?, anyway, why don't you use a config file containing a plain object with the required keys?

Comment: Client side. What do you mean by config file? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409306/gulp-task-to-create-a-dev-and-prod-version-of-main-js/24441072#24441072

Comment: Thanks, that may work. But I don't need a whole new file for each environment. I need to replace just a few lines. What I don't like is keeping the environment dependent files in the repository. I would rather like to have a generic code base, which imports settings from environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution based on suggestion in the comments.
I created `settings.ENV.js` files containing all setting variables, where `ENV` is `prod`, `dev`, `test`, etc.

Then to change the environment just I copy one of tese files to settings.js, which is included in the client side code. For convenience I made a `grunt` task that does the copy:

```
grunt use:dev
```